# prove that n is an eigenvalue of an n by n matrix A, and find a corresponding eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an n by n matrix. How do I prove that n is an eigenvalue of this matrix? I know it will have at most n distinct eigenvalues, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there...

Also, how do I then find its corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: Is the size $n$ of the square matrix also an eigenvalue of that matrix? This is something that happens in some cases, but not typically.

Comment: @AIN Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By definition $n$ is an eigenvalue if

- $A\vec v=n \vec v \iff (A-nI)\vec v=0$ for $\vec v\neq 0 \iff det(A-nI)=0$
- once we have found $n$ then from $(A-nI)\vec v=0$ find the eigenvector(s) $\vec v$

Comment: @AIN In this case we can try with $\vec v=(1,1,1,...,1)$ then $Av=nv$